# Salvar e-mail caixa de saída

Tags: delphi, email, envio-de-email, delphi-7

Gostaria de saber se é possível salvar um e-mail na caixa de saída do gerenciador padrão de e-mail (Outlook, live mail, entre outros) usando o Indy10.

Hoje já tenho uma função para enviar e-mail, porém chama a tela de novo e-mail do gerenciador para cada mensagem. Isso para um único e-mail funciona bem, porém se for uma mala direta ai já fica ruim, pois irá abrir uma nova janela para cada e-mail.

Abaixo rotina para enviar o e-mail.

```
IdMessage.Clear;
IdMessage.Subject := 'Assunto teste';
idMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';;
IdMessage.Body.Text := 'texto do email';
AdicionarDestinario(IdMessage.Recipients, 'email@email.com.br');

Arquivo := 'c:\emails\email.eml';
IdMessage.SaveToFile(Arquivo);

ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(Arquivo), '','', SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Ariel, posta seu código, acredito que enviar para a caixa de saída não seja possível, porém vamos esperar. Mas talvez alterar seu código para não exibir nova janela para cada e-mail.

Comment: @David, esta é a rotina que gera o e-mail.

Comment: Se você já está usando indy para criar sua mensagem, por que não ir além e enviar a mensagem por Indy? Assim você não depende de outros programas.

Comment: Mas respondendo sua pergunta, acho que você não vai conseguir fazer isso de maneira genérica para o gerenciador de e-mail padrão. Provavelmente você teria que descobrir onde o gerenciador de e-mail armazena sua caixa de saída e salvar sua mensagem lá no formato dele. Então teria que ser personalizado para cada programa.